magento 2 newsletter subscription block custom column with options
on magento 2 we can add additional columns to the subscribers grid by using the  newsletter_subscription_block layout xml file. The original file in the Magento\Newsletter module has the column for type guest/customer set as this:
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.type" as="type">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">type</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="guest" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Guest</item>
            </item>
            <item name="customer" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>               

But the column "type" is not present in the database table, so how is this column generated?
I tried to test this code with a custom column that I had previously added to the newsletter subscribers table:
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.type" as="mycolumn">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">mycolumn</argument>
        <argument name="mycolumn" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="guest" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Guest</item>
            </item>
            <item name="customer" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>               

But this code does not work. I can see my column, but it displays the original values as they are saved in the database (1 or 2), not the labels.
I also thought the original module was using the UIComponent Providers to edit the information displayed in the column but there is no Ui folder in the module-newsletter folder.
How can we re-create the same logic as the "type" column with our own custom columns?

Please use the below code for your requirement, instead of your_custom_column_name use your own column name and against your each value map your own label that you want to display as text in place of Your Label 1,Your Label 2,Your Label 3 and Your Label 4 and also please make sure to set proper value as saved in your column.
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet.mycolumn" as="mycolumn">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">your_custom_column_name</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="option1" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label 1</item>
            </item>
            <item name="option2" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label 2</item>
            </item>
            <item name="option3" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label 3</item>
            </item>
            <item name="option4" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label 4</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-mycolumn</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-mycolumn</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>

If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding

Hello @Lou Nik, if this fixed your problem please let me know, or if you still need any help.

Sorry I didn't see you replied. It works! Thanks
